# Send automatic whatsapp message using puppeteer and express js

Tags: node.js, express, puppeteer, qr-code, whatsapp

I am trying to send whatsapp message to one of my contact using puppeteer lib in express server. To send message i have to authorize my whatsapp via web.whatsapp.com qr code.

Using puppeteer i am trying to take screenshot of the whatsapp web qrcode and send as a response to HTTP GET request in my express server. But when i try to scan the qrcode i am getting a error like "**cant scan code. Make sure you are on whatsapp web and try again**". Below code for the same;

```
app.get("/handshake",((req,res,next)=>{
  console.log(req.body);

  (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3641.0 Safari/537.36');
      await page.goto(WHATSAPP_LOGIN_URL, {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2",
      });
      await page.setViewport({
        width: 1024,
        height: 800,
      });
      const qrElement = await page.$("#app > div > div > div.landing-window > div.landing-main > div > div._3l6Cf > div");
      await qrElement.screenshot({path:"./whatsapp.jpg",type:"jpeg"});
      await browser.close();
      res.sendFile("./whatsapp.jpg",{root:__dirname});        

    })()

  }))
```

As a workaround, Using puppeteer i am able to access the div that contains the div of the qr code in which the i am getting the value of data-ref attribute and converting the value to qr code using qrcode npm module which i am sending as a response to my GET HTTP req in express server. If i try to scan the qr code, whatsapp is showing the same error "**cant scan code. Make sure you are whatsapp web and try again**". Below is my code for the same;

```
app.get("/handshake",((req,res,next)=>{
  console.log(req.body);

  (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3641.0 Safari/537.36');
      await page.goto(WHATSAPP_LOGIN_URL, {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2",
      });
      await page.setViewport({
        width: 1024,
        height: 800,
      });
       const dataref = await page.evaluate(()=>{
         return document.getElementsByClassName('_1yHR2')[0].dataset.ref;
      })
       console.log(dataref);
      const qrElement = await page.$("#app > div > div > div.landing-window > div.landing-main > div > div._3l6Cf > div");
      await qrElement.screenshot({path:"./whatsapp.jpg",type:"jpeg"});
      await browser.close();

       res.send(QRCode.toString(dataref,{type:"png"},function(err,url){
         console.log(url)

       }))

    })()

  }))
```

The above 2 method doesnt work. But when i manually take the value of the data-ref attr using chrome inspect element and paste https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/ and generate the value as a qrcode and scan using mobile whatsapp qr scanner, whatsapp is able authorise me without any error. How is this possible ? i am trying to do the exact same thing using postman.

Let me know what i am missing here.

[Postman screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbHFh.png)

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end?